# How to config ferret 0.11.5-mswin32 and acts_as_ferret 0.4.4 on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, windows-7

I'm using Rails 3 and I want to use `ferret` in my app. I installed `ferret 0.11.5-mswin32` (because i work on windows 7) and `acts_as_ferret 0.4.4`.

In my `Gemfile` I have:

```
gem 'ferret'   
gem 'acts_as_ferret'
```

Then when I start the server I get this error:

```
Could not find gem 'ferret (>= 0)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
```

I have tried with

```
gem 'ferret', '0.11.5'   
gem 'acts_as_ferret', '0.4.4'
```

and I still get the same error.

What do I need to put my Gemfile to get `ferret` working?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The docs on acts_as_ferret stipulate you need version 0.5 or greater for rails 3, and ferret 0.11.8 (I would use 11.8.4 since it is the only release of the gem in 4 years...and that is a bit of a red flag).

No offense, but why are you using ferret?

A few years ago, that was a good idea, but since then other search engines have been better adopted and supported (sphinx, elastic search, solr).

Comment: I don't found a acts_as_ferret gem that no throw error about Makefile except the version 0.4.4

Comment: I use a sqlite database, what do you recomend me?

Comment: sqlite is fine for development, but not any kind of production application.  Get a different db, like postgres, which also happens to have nice full text searching (e.g. texticle gem). Or use mysql, and thinking sphinx is good.

Comment: a last bit of advice (upvote? accept?): sqlite does have full text search capabilities if that is what you are stuck with: http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html